# Finding where the C "Common" wire should be in my heating unit

Tags: wiring, central-heating

I'm trying to understand where the common wire would be from my system's wiring diagram. The thermostat itself only has the R and W connected.

Is my understanding correct that it would be the wire leading to 'earth' from the transformer in the below diagram?

[image]
[image]

Any help or info is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system has no "C" wire brought out to the connector.  This is not uncommon as many systems don't.  If you need a "C" wire, you'll want to connect it here:

[image]